# Can iOS apps be removed from iTunes Music Folder after upgrading to iTunes 12.7?

Tags: itunes, applications

[image: iTunes no longer syncs apps]

Now that iTunes no longer syncs apps to iOS devices, can apps be removed from the folder that iTunes stored them in? (`~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Mobile Applications` in my case)

I have updated iTunes, and was surprised to see that the applications were not deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the .ipa files can be safely removed/deleted, since iTunes 12.7 will no longer use them.

However, if an app is no longer available for download again, you can restore via the old .ipa file, per this [TechCrunch article](https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/12/apple-streamlines-itunes-12-7-by-removing-the-app-store/) (includes Apple support links):

> People who have been syncing apps through iTunes need to [redownload
>   them onto their devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201272#apps). Previously downloaded iOS apps, ringtones
>   and books for PC can be found in the iTunes Media folder, but if
>   something is no longer available to download again, it can [still be
>   transferred from computer to iOS devices with a USB cable](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201593).

Also this [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208075) notes:

> If you have an iOS app, ringtone, or book that's no longer available
>   for redownload, you can [move that content to your iOS device while
>   plugged in to a computer with a USB cabl](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201593)e.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: YES you can delete the folder.

The longer answer is: It depends on which apps you have. If you have some apps that you no longer can download from the App Store, you still need them as a backup, so that you can drop them onto your device when/if needed. So you can delete the apps that you know you still can update/download from the App Store.

And when you decide if you still need the old app, you should also see at the app’s spec. - is it a 32-bit or a 64-bit app ?? only 64-bit will work with iOS 11